# SplitViewController only displays white screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen, uisplitviewcontroller, ios13

I have had a published universal app for many years that has worked fine.  Now since the iOS13 update it simply starts to a solid white screen.  The only exception is if I run it on an iPad and change orientation of the device.  Than the app finally appears as it always has.  I have placed a breakpoint in my delegate file in the Application method and another in my rootviewcontroller in the viewDidLoad method.  In iOS 12 both breakpoints get hit and everything runs as it always has.  In iOS 13 the rootviewcontroller breakpoint never gets reached.  The app is very old and uses plain old XIB files with no Storyboards.

The code in my delegate is this;

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window, splitViewController;

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [self.window setRootViewController:self.splitViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with iOS 13 Split view controller. If you have navigation controller embedded to Master/Detail view controller it just loads the navigation controller.

To fix that issue create a custom class from UISplitViewController and assign that to your splitviewcontroller in storyboard and programatically add Navigation controller and masterViewcontroller to that UISplitViewController. That should load your view properly. This code goes in the viewdidload or willappear of the UISplitviewcontroller class.
Sample code.

```
    MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *tableViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:master];
    UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tableViewNavigationController,navC, nil];
```

This fixed my issue had similar problem with iOS. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help.  Your last line of code throws an error for me since viewControllers is not instantiated.  Not sure where this object originates.  Exact error is; Property 'viewControllers' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Comment: Error is because 'AppDelegate' is not subclass on UISplitViewController. As I have mention you can create custom class of UISplitViewController and assign that to your splitviewcontroller. This property 'viewControllers' is for UISplitViewController.